# Issue in ESP8266

Tags: lua, iot, esp8266

I have been working on controlling an LED through ESP8266 using an Android app. I have used the [Random Nerd Tutorials website](https://randomnerdtutorials.com) for my reference.

The following is the code which I used:

```
wifi.setmode(wifi.STATION)
wifi.sta.config("YOUR_NETWORK_NAME","YOUR_NETWORK_PASSWORD")
print(wifi.sta.getip())
led1 = 3
led2 = 4
gpio.mode(led1, gpio.OUTPUT)
gpio.mode(led2, gpio.OUTPUT)
srv=net.createServer(net.TCP)
srv:listen(80,function(conn)
    conn:on("receive", function(client,request)
        local buf = "";
        buf = buf.."HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n\n"
        local _, _, method, path, vars = string.find(request, "([A-Z]+) (.+)?(.+) HTTP");
        if(method == nil)then
            _, _, method, path = string.find(request, "([A-Z]+) (.+) HTTP");
        end
        local _GET = {}
        if (vars ~= nil)then
            for k, v in string.gmatch(vars, "(%w+)=(%w+)&*") do
                _GET[k] = v
            end
        end

        if(_GET.pin == "ON1")then
              gpio.write(led1, gpio.HIGH);
        elseif(_GET.pin == "OFF1")then
              gpio.write(led1, gpio.LOW);
        elseif(_GET.pin == "ON2")then
              gpio.write(led2, gpio.HIGH);
        elseif(_GET.pin == "OFF2")then
              gpio.write(led2, gpio.LOW);
        end
        client:send(buf);
        client:close();
        collectgarbage();
    end)
end)
```

There are no errors in the code. The connections also seem right. I uploaded the code named as 'init.lua' into the ESP8266 using ESPlorer and was also able to control the LEDs through the app. But the next day when I tried controlling the LEDS I failed. Should I upload the code every time I unpower the ESP8266 module? What could be the issue?

Comment: Assuming you saved the program to flash, the next thing to look at is whether you named it correctly or not.  NodeMCU expects to find a file named "init.lua" and runs that at power-on.  What (if any) error you'd be getting from the UART will reveal whether you're getting a bad filename or what.  It's also worth putting some debug prints in the code so you can see status from the UART.

Comment: @pycoder That's not true. Lua files aren't saved in RAM.

Comment: @darshita-uma is this solved or do you need more information?

Comment: Thanks for the informations. The issue was resloved.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of "issues".

- You seem to be running on older firmware. `wifi.sta.config` now expects the parameters in a Lua table: https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/en/modules/wifi/#wifistaconfig
- As many other functions in NodeMCU `wifi.sta.config` is non-blocking. You need to wait with any networking related functions until you get connected to the access point. Running `print(wifi.sta.getip())` immediately afterwards is likely going to "fail" i.e. not printing anything useful because you don't *have* an IP yet.
- Save your application in a file called `init.lua` to persist it across power cycles.

An example for the last two is documented at https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/en/upload/#initlua

Answer (score 0):

Every time when you turn on your ESP8266 your router (DNS) assign new IP address to ESP8266.

Comment: It looks like you need to write more explanations especially that the asker has a code and maybe you should point to the lines that he should modify